# Peak detection comparator simulation problem.(Process and no VSS version)

Tags: comparator

Here is a peak detection comparator schematic and simulation,i have three question about them.

1.Why is there a high signal in C point,but not in A and B point?

2.There is VSS in this peak detection comparator schematic,is there a peak detection comparator schematic without VSS in it? I connect it with gnd,but the wave is wrong.

[image]

(1) peak detection comparator schematic

[image]
(2) peak detection comparator simulation

The purple line is the \$V_{PZT}\$,and the blue line is the \$V_D\$,the red one is the output of comparator,that is ,\$V_{CP_PK}\$

Comment: It seems that you did not show us the whole circuit. What is the source that drives the comparator? Where is the capacitor Cp? What are the voltages involved? You must provide a lot more infos if you want some good answers.

Comment: @StefanWyss sorry,i will explain more in this question,i have edit the question

Comment: Ok, a tiny bit clearer now. I still don‘t get your VSS question. VSS is the lower supply terminal of this circuit and of course you must connect it to GND, because the voltage there defines the lowest voltage that can be  seen at the output Vcp. This explains why you see „nothing“ at B: The red line can not go below 0V/GND. Explanation for A is, that the voltage difference of the input signals is too tiny to trigger the comparator output.

Comment: @StefanWyss Do you mean i see nothing at B because i connect the VSS to gnd?For this simulation,i connect the VSS as -VDD

Comment: It depends on your input circuit. Can you show us that? And how much voltage is VDD? Where did you connect the other triangle terminal in the circuit?

Comment: My previous comment is not quite ok. It is the triangle terminal that defines the lower output voltage of this circuit.

Comment: The circuit shown is a comparator with hysteresis. Hysteresis is controlled by MPL1 and MPL2. You can reduce the amount of hysteresis by reducing their W/L ratios. If there is no external circuit the output should be more or less digital.